# Función JavaScript que reciba datos de unas listas desplegables de fechas y muestre en HTML el resultado

Tags: javascript, html, lista, script

Tengo este código HTML, que es una lista desplegable de año, mes y día. Eso funciona; pero no me funciona la función JavaScript que reciba la selección de un año, mes y día especifico. Y además mostrar como resultado a que signo del zodiaco chino correspondería. ¡Alguna ayuda! Eso, no se si se entiende.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Horoscopo Chino</title>    
</head>
<body>

<h1>Encuentra tu signo del horóscopo chino</h1>
<h2>Elija su fecha de nacimiento y descubra su signo de horóscopo chino.</h2>

<form>
<tr>
    <th>
<select name="AÑO">
    <option value="1">1921</option>
    <option value="2">1922</option>
    <option value="3">1923</option>
    <option value="4">1924</option> 
    <option value="5">1925</option> 
    <option value="6">1926</option>
    <option value="7">1927</option>
    <option value="8">1928</option>
    <option value="9">1929</option>
    <option value="10">1930</option>
    <option value="11">1931</option>
    <option value="12">1932</option>
    <option value="13">1933</option>
    <option value="14">1934</option>
    <option value="15">1935</option>
    <option value="16">1936</option>
    <option value="17">1937</option>
    <option value="18">1938</option>
    <option value="19">1939</option>
    <option value="20">1940</option>
    <option value="21">1941</option>
    <option value="22">1942</option>
    <option value="23">1943</option>
    <option value="24">1944</option>
    <option value="25">1945</option>
    <option value="26">1946</option>
    <option value="27">1947</option>
    <option value="28">1948</option>
    <option value="29">1949</option>
    <option value="30">1950</option>
    <option value="31">1951</option>
    <option value="32">1952</option>
    <option value="33">1953</option>
    <option value="34">1954</option>
    <option value="35">1955</option>
    <option value="36">1956</option>
    <option value="37">1957</option>
    <option value="38">1958</option>
    <option value="39">1959</option>
    <option value="40">1960</option>
    <option value="41">1961</option>
    <option value="42">1962</option>
    <option value="43">1963</option>
    <option value="44">1964</option>
    <option value="45">1965</option>
    <option value="46">1966</option>
    <option value="47">1967</option>
    <option value="48">1968</option>
    <option value="49">1969</option>
    <option value="50">1970</option>
    <option value="51">1971</option>
    <option value="52">1972</option>
    <option value="53">1973</option>
    <option value="54">1974</option>
    <option value="55">1975</option>
    <option value="56">1976</option>
    <option value="57">1977</option>
    <option value="58">1978</option>
    <option value="59">1979</option>
    <option value="60">1980</option>
    <option value="61">1981</option>
    <option value="62">1982</option>
    <option value="63">1983</option>
    <option value="64">1984</option>
    <option value="65">1985</option>
    <option value="66">1986</option>
    <option value="67">1987</option>
    <option value="68">1988</option>
    <option value="69">1989</option>
    <option value="70">1990</option>
    <option value="71">1991</option>
    <option value="72">1992</option>
    <option value="73">1993</option>
    <option value="74">1994</option>
    <option value="75">1995</option>
    <option value="76">1996</option>
    <option value="77">1997</option>
    <option value="78">1998</option>
    <option value="79">1999</option>
    <option value="80">2000</option>
    <option value="81">2001</option>
    <option value="82">2002</option>
    <option value="83">2003</option>
    <option value="84">2004</option>
    <option value="85">2005</option>
    <option value="86">2006</option>
    <option value="87">2007</option>
    <option value="88">2008</option>
    <option value="89">2009</option>
    <option value="90">2010</option>
    <option value="91">2011</option>
    <option value="92">2012</option>
    <option value="93">2013</option>
    <option value="94">2014</option>
    <option value="95">2015</option>
    <option value="96">2016</option>
    <option value="97">2017</option>
    <option value="98">2018</option>
    <option value="99">2019</option>
    <option value="100">2020</option>
    
</select>
    </th>
    <th>
    <select name="MES">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option> 
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option> 
        <option value="5">5</option> 
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
    </th>
    <th>
            <select name="DIA">
            <option value="1">1</option> 
            <option value="2">2</option> 
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option> 
            <option value="5">5</option> 
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
            
</select>
    </th>
</tr>
    <input type="button" value="Consultar" onclick="getElements()" class="button-enviar">
    </form>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function getElements(){
        var x = document.getElementsByName("rata");
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "RATA";
    }
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entiende tu idea, sería bueno que trabajes con DOM.
Te recomiendo que investigues este par de funciones:

> [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> [document.getElementById()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

> [document.getElementsByTagName()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp)

Te van a servir de mucho para obtener datos y manipular los elementos en tu HTML.

```js
<script>
      const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
      const form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].children;
      function getElements() {
        
        let year = form[0].value;
        let month = form[1].value;
        let day = form[2].value;
        // year
        console.log(year);

        //month
        console.log(month);

        //day
        console.log(day);

        //set demo
        demo.innerText = `J'adore JS!\n${year}-${month}-${day}`;
      }
    </script>
```

Si te resulta más fácil, podrías usar de framework Jquery, aunque al parecer, no es muy recomendable hoy en día.

¡Saludos!
JS!

Answer (score 0):

Es más sencillo si pones a cada select un id para luego buscar ese elemento usando `document.getElementById('elemento')`. En el ejemplo, la función `consultar()` es llamada cuando se hace click al botón consultar. La función busca los select por sus id y guarda el valor seleccionado en una variable. Ya con eso se puede implementar la lógica necesaria.

```js
function consultar(){

let año = document.getElementById('año').value;
let mes = document.getElementById('mes').value;
let dia = document.getElementById('dia').value;


console.log(`el año es: ${año} el mes es ${mes}  el dia es: ${dia}`)


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Horoscopo Chino</title>    
</head>
<body>

<h1>Encuentra tu signo del horóscopo chino</h1>
<h2>Elija su fecha de nacimiento y descubra su signo de horóscopo chino.</h2>

<form>
<tr>
    <th>
<select name="AÑO" id="año">
    <option value="1">1921</option>
    <option value="2">1922</option>
    <option value="3">1923</option>
    <option value="4">1924</option> 
    <option value="5">1925</option> 
    <option value="6">1926</option>
    <option value="7">1927</option>
    <option value="8">1928</option>
    <option value="9">1929</option>
    <option value="10">1930</option>
    <option value="11">1931</option>
    <option value="12">1932</option>
    <option value="13">1933</option>
    <option value="14">1934</option>
    <option value="15">1935</option>
    <option value="16">1936</option>
    <option value="17">1937</option>
    <option value="18">1938</option>
    <option value="19">1939</option>
    <option value="20">1940</option>
    <option value="21">1941</option>
    <option value="22">1942</option>
    <option value="23">1943</option>
    <option value="24">1944</option>
    <option value="25">1945</option>
    <option value="26">1946</option>
    <option value="27">1947</option>
    <option value="28">1948</option>
    <option value="29">1949</option>
    <option value="30">1950</option>
    <option value="31">1951</option>
    <option value="32">1952</option>
    <option value="33">1953</option>
    <option value="34">1954</option>
    <option value="35">1955</option>
    <option value="36">1956</option>
    <option value="37">1957</option>
    <option value="38">1958</option>
    <option value="39">1959</option>
    <option value="40">1960</option>
    <option value="41">1961</option>
    <option value="42">1962</option>
    <option value="43">1963</option>
    <option value="44">1964</option>
    <option value="45">1965</option>
    <option value="46">1966</option>
    <option value="47">1967</option>
    <option value="48">1968</option>
    <option value="49">1969</option>
    <option value="50">1970</option>
    <option value="51">1971</option>
    <option value="52">1972</option>
    <option value="53">1973</option>
    <option value="54">1974</option>
    <option value="55">1975</option>
    <option value="56">1976</option>
    <option value="57">1977</option>
    <option value="58">1978</option>
    <option value="59">1979</option>
    <option value="60">1980</option>
    <option value="61">1981</option>
    <option value="62">1982</option>
    <option value="63">1983</option>
    <option value="64">1984</option>
    <option value="65">1985</option>
    <option value="66">1986</option>
    <option value="67">1987</option>
    <option value="68">1988</option>
    <option value="69">1989</option>
    <option value="70">1990</option>
    <option value="71">1991</option>
    <option value="72">1992</option>
    <option value="73">1993</option>
    <option value="74">1994</option>
    <option value="75">1995</option>
    <option value="76">1996</option>
    <option value="77">1997</option>
    <option value="78">1998</option>
    <option value="79">1999</option>
    <option value="80">2000</option>
    <option value="81">2001</option>
    <option value="82">2002</option>
    <option value="83">2003</option>
    <option value="84">2004</option>
    <option value="85">2005</option>
    <option value="86">2006</option>
    <option value="87">2007</option>
    <option value="88">2008</option>
    <option value="89">2009</option>
    <option value="90">2010</option>
    <option value="91">2011</option>
    <option value="92">2012</option>
    <option value="93">2013</option>
    <option value="94">2014</option>
    <option value="95">2015</option>
    <option value="96">2016</option>
    <option value="97">2017</option>
    <option value="98">2018</option>
    <option value="99">2019</option>
    <option value="100">2020</option>
    
</select>
    </th>
    <th>
    <select name="MES" id="mes">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option> 
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option> 
        <option value="5">5</option> 
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
    </th>
    <th>
            <select name="DIA" id="dia">
            <option value="1">1</option> 
            <option value="2">2</option> 
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option> 
            <option value="5">5</option> 
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
            
</select>
    </th>
</tr>
    <input type="button" value="Consultar" onclick="consultar()" class="button-enviar">
    </form>

<p id="demo"></p>
   
</body>
</html>
```